# No callback when calling yam.platform.login

Tags: yammer

When using Yammer SDK and using yam.platform.login method, I don't get any callback when authentication fails or when the user closes dialog window.  Is this a bug or something you have seen in your Yammer integration tasks?

My code

```
yam.platform.getLoginStatus(function (response) {
    if (response.authResponse) {
    }
    else {
        yam.platform.login(function (response) {
            if (response.authResponse) {
                console.dir(response);
            }
            else {
               ### CODE NEVER EXECUTED IF LOGIN FAILS OR USER CLOSE POPUP###
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure to add your web application url to "Javascript Origins" of your registered yammer app.
2. Make sure you added your web app url to "Trusted Sites" and other Yammer urls.

Answer (score 0):

We get this problem (no callback on yam.platform.login) when the user is currently logged into a network other than the home network (network where app is registered).  If your users use multiple networks, you may need to add your app to the global app register.

An alternative (hacky) way is to 'try' the approach below.  This worked for us as it only needed to happen once (to get the auth token).

```
  yam.getLoginStatus(function(resp){
    if (resp.authResponse) {
      //success
    } else {
      // not logged in 
      var yamLoginSuccess=0;
      try {
        yam.platform.login( function (response) { //prompt login
          console.log('no response here if user in another network');
          if (response.authResponse) {
            //success
            yamLoginSuccess=1;
          } 
        });
      }
      catch(err) {
          // does not throw an error so this bit is not helpful
      }
      finally{
        if(yamLoginSuccess===0){
          alert('Need to be logged into the home yammer first :-/ /n '
            + 'Redirecting now, hit back to come back');
          window.location='https://www.yammer.com/YOURNETWORK/';
        }
      }
    }
  });
```